# ListView.DataItem is showing null

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Listview binding code

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="leftColumnPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <asp:ListView ID="lvQuestions" runat="server" OnItemDataBound='lvQuestions_ItemDataBound'>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
            </div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitAnswers" runat="server" Text="Submit Answers" OnClick="btnSubmitAnswers_Click" />
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div>
                <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>:<%# Eval("Body") %>
            </div>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdlAnswers" runat="server" DataSource='<%#Eval("ExamAnswer") %>' DataTextField='Body' DataValueField="AnswerId">
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</asp:Content>
```

> While fetching the listview items on submit button click..like below,
>   we are getting qsnItem.DataItem as **NULL**.

```
foreach (ListViewDataItem qsnItem in lvQuestions.Items)
{
}
```

Please suggest what is going wrong here.

Comment: How can we know that you have a data on your listview?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DataItem` of all databound web-controls in ASP.NET are `null` on postbacks when you don't `DataBind` the control again, which is unnecessary when `ViewState` is enabled(default).

So you can use the controls in your templates to get the values:

```
foreach (ListViewDataItem qsnItem in lvQuestions.Items)
{
    RadioButtonList rdlAnswers = (RadioButtonList)qsnItem.FindControl("rdlAnswers");
}
```

If you need to old values you need to load them from database or use the [`ListViewUpdatedEventArgs.OldValues`  Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewupdatedeventargs.oldvalues.aspx).

Comment: Rebinding has nothing to do with it (I rebind on Postback and the data items are still missing). According to the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewdataitem.dataitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the "DataItem property is available only during and after the ItemDataBound event of a ListView control".

Comment: @bvgheluwe: of course you have to provide the `DataSource` before you call `DataBind`, then the `DataItem`s are available afterwards(f.e in `ListView.ItemDataBound` or in `ListView.DataBound`). But you should not require the `DataItem`s anyway on postback since the values are stored in ViewState anyway(see above).

Comment: I know that they are available in `ItemDataBound` and `DataBound`, but my findings are that it's not the case (anymore) in a following `Button.Click` event handler.

Comment: @bvgheluwe: that's not true(afaik). The `DataItem` of all items in a `ListView` (or rows in a `GridView`etc.) are available across the whole lifecycle of the page after the control was databound. This is also documented(at least in [`GridViewRow.DataItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem(v=vs.110).aspx)): _"Use the DataItem property to access the properties of the underlying data object to which the GridViewRow object is bound. The DataItem property is only available during **and after** the RowDataBound event of a GridView control."_

Comment: I think we misunderstand eachother. `ListView.Items` is a collection of `ListViewDataItem`. This collection is indeed not empty in the `Button.Click` event handler (or any other moment in the page life cycle after databinding). `ListViewDataItem` has a property `DataItem` which seems to be available only during `ItemDataBound`. When the datasource is a collection of pocos, the `DataItem` is one of those.  I was hoping to be able to re-use this poco in `Button.Click` when posting back (after rebinding), without having to walk the control tree to read the individual controls.

Comment: @bvgheluwe: ... but when you've tried `var btn = (Button) sender;
            var item = (ListViewDataItem) btn.NamingContainer;
            var data = item.DataItem;` it was null?

Comment: The button is just a button on the page (outside of the ListView), so I don't think that the `NamingContainer` of the button will be the ListView. My goal is to process al the items in 2 separate ListViews at once. I'm doing the rebinding (after indeed resetting the datasource) in OnInit b/c I want the values that are in the POST body to be reapplied (i.e. I don't want the rebinding to overwrite the user supplied values).