# Passing DataSource ID to code-behind on checkbox check

Tags: c#, asp.net

I currently have a ListView that I'm populating with a bound Collection that I'm populating from a pre-existing database.

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <tr>                       
        <td><asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" /></td>         
        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "team_name") %></td>
        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "team_city") %></td>
        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "team_stateprov") %></td>
        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "team_country") %></td>
     </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Essentially what I'm looking to do is this: When I click my Delete button I want to find every chkDelete that is checked, and get the corresponding Container.DataItem of "id" into the codebehind so I can process the deletion from there. Is it possible? If so, how should I go about it?

Comment: Can you show more code? Did you try anything?

Comment: It's just a ListView with a DataPager and the DataSource set on Page_Load. What code would you like to see?

And I haven't tried anything specific yet.

Comment: I would like to see your try, to help you where you are stuck.

Comment: It will not help you but it will be easier to type in the future. You can write just `<%#Eval("team_name") %>` instead of `<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "team_name") %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to iterate through the [`ListView.Items` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.items%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to accomplish this.

In your delete button click event, you would just need something like this:

```
// Create some collection to store the IDs
List<string> itemsToDelete = new List<string>();

// Loop through all of the items, check if the box 
// is checked, add to list if it is
foreach (ListViewItem item in yourListView.Items)
{
    CheckBox chkDelete = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("chkDelete");
    if(chkDelete.Checked)
    {
        string yourID = item.DataItem["id"].ToString();
        itemsToDelete.Add(yourID);
    }
}
```

Note: I *think* you can access the DataItem fields the way I described above.  If that doesn't work, then you have to cast it to a DataRowView and grab it that way:

```
DataRowView data = (DataRowView)item.DataItem;
string yourID = data["id"].ToString();
```

It's been a while since I worked with this control, so I'm just not positive.  But one of those should do the trick.

Comment: The code to access the various checkboxes works perfectly - it's exactly what I needed. However, it doesn't let me access the DataItem - it says all of them are null, regardless of how I try to access them.

Comment: @CJWilliams For every `item.DataItem`? Or just some? I wonder if the ListView isn't databound yet when the click event fires. Or something weird like that.  If it's just some of them, it might help to throw an `if(item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)` block around the code inside the loop, just to be safe.

Comment: The ListView is bound at the point that the click event fires, because I bind it on Page_Load. I can see that the Databound data is present in the ListView before I click. However, the ListViewItem.DataItem is null when I try to access it from the button click/via the checkbox.

Comment: To test if it was an issue with the binding, I added the ID to the tooltip: `<asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" ToolTip='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id") %>' />` This works, and the proper information is stored in the tooltip, and I can get it out of the checkbox object. Not an ideal solution by any stretch, but it shows that the concept works.

Comment: @CJWilliams Ah, I forget that the [DataItem properties are null on PostBacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231918/listview-dataitem-is-showing-null), because ViewState is handling all of that for you (I imagine you're binding data in a `if(!IsPostBack)` block, so it's not really bound every time). That Tooltip idea might be your best bet.

Comment: Well that makes sense! Thank you very much for your help. Longshot, but do you know of any way to prevent tooltips from displaying? I'd rather not have the ID sitting out in plain text if I can avoid it.

Comment: @CJWilliams Unfortunately, I do not know how to stop tooltips from displaying. You could just put the value in an `<asp:HiddenField>` control. It would still be on your page, but only in the markup, so your general users wouldn't really notice it.

Comment: I'll play around with that. And I was planning on doing so! Hahaha. Thank you very much.

Comment: @CJWilliams Great minds think alike and all that ;-)  You're very welcome!  I'm glad I could help.